# How do I check if wscript/cscript runs on x64 host OS?

Tags: vbscript, registry, 64-bit, wsh

I'm running a VBScript that may run under x64 Windows. I need to read a registry key from the 32-bit part of the registry. For that I use path `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\xyz` instead of `HKLM\Software\xyz`. How can I check if the script is executed under x64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to check if the script is executing under x64.

Try to read from `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\xyz`, if that fails, try to read from `HKLM\Software\xyz`, if that fails, your registry key doesn't exist, take whatever action is appropriate.

Of course, if your design is more complicated (for example, you write a value into that registry key if it doesn't exist) then that suggestion won't work.

Here is a VBScript for examining the operating system. You'll probably also need explanation of the [Properties available from the Win32_OperatingSystem Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(VS.85).aspx)

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")        

Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
    msg = objOperatingSystem.Caption & " " & _
            objOperatingSystem.Version & " " & _
                objOperatingSystem.OSArchitecture
    msgbox msg
Next
```

Note that for Windows XP and 2003, `OSArchitecture` is not available, in which case you will probably have to examine either the `Caption` or `Version` to determine whether your OS is 64-bit.

You could also use something like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/garretts/archive/2006/08/04/688788.aspx) depending on the level of complexity you require.

Comment: I'm just reading from a specific key, so the test for reading from the node in Wow6432Node is enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Even on 64-bit version of Windows you script can execute in 32-bit mode.

You can use following code to determine real bit mode, you script running on:

```vb
option explicit

function Determine64BitMode
    dim Shell, Is64BitOs
    set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    on error resume next
    Shell.RegRead "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir (x86)"
    Is64BitOs = Err.Number = 0
    on error goto 0
    if Is64BitOs then
        Determine64BitMode = InStr(Shell.RegRead("HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir"), "(x86)") = 0
    else
        Determine64BitMode = false
    end if
end function

dim ExecutingIn64BitMode
ExecutingIn64BitMode = Determine64BitMode
if ExecutingIn64BitMode then
    MsgBox "64 bit"
else
    MsgBox "32 bit"
end if
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on the Microsoft knowledgebase article [How To Check If Computer Is Running A 32 Bit or 64 Bit Operating System](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556009):

```vb
Function Is64BitOS()
    Is64BitOS = Not(Is32BitOS())
End Function

Function Is32BitOS()
    Const sRegKey = "HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0"
    Const sIdentifierValue = "Identifier"
    Const sPlatformIDValue = "Platform ID"

    Dim oSh : Set oSh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim sIdentifier, nPlatformID

    sIdentifier = oSh.RegRead(sRegKey & "\" & sIdentifierValue)
    nPlatformID = oSh.RegRead(sRegKey & "\" & sPlatformIDValue)

    Set oSh = Nothing

    If InStr(sIdentifier, "x86") > 0 And nPlatformID = 32 Then
        Is32BitOS = True
    Else
        Is32BitOS = False
    End if
End Function
```

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION**

An alternative and more concise solution that makes use of **WMI** can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13979562/1497596).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what API you use to read from the registry. For example, if you use the WMI [`StdRegProv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393664.aspx) class, you can use the `__ProviderArchitecture` flag to request access to the 32-bit registry hive regardless of whether the script is run under 32-bit or 64-bit Windows Script Host. This technique is described in the [Requesting WMI Data on a 64-bit Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393067.aspx) article in MSDN.

Here's an example of reading from the 32-bit registry:

```
strComputer = "."
Const HKLM = &h80000002

''# Specify the required registry bitness
Set oCtx = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemNamedValueSet")
oCtx.Add "__ProviderArchitecture", 32
oCtx.Add "__RequiredArchitecture", True

''# Load the 32-bit registry provider
Set oLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set oWMI = oLocator.ConnectServer(strComputer, "root\default",,,,,, oCtx)
Set oReg = oWMI.Get("StdRegProv") 

''# Specify input parameters for the GetStringValue method call
Set oInParams = oReg.Methods_("GetStringValue").InParameters
oInParams.hDefKey     = HKLM
oInParams.sSubKeyName = "Software\xyz"
oInParams.sValueName  = "foobar"

''# Read a string value from the registry
Set oOutParams = oReg.ExecMethod_("GetStringValue", oInParams,, oCtx)
WScript.Echo oOutParams.sValue
```

Note also, that in this case the 32-bit key names should be specified in a usual way as `HKLM\Software\xyz` instead of `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\xyz`.

Answer (score 1):

This shows both the system and process architectures:

```
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell, WshEnv
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshEnv = WshShell.Environment("System")
MsgBox "System: " & WshEnv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")
Set WshEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process")
MsgBox "Process: " & WshEnv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")
```

Just check the one you need for `<> "x86"`.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to check whether (virtual) folder `C:\Windows\sysnative` exist. This folder exists only in 32-Bit processes, see [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/file-system-redirector)

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

If fso.FolderExists(wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%") & "\sysnative" ) Then
    WScript.Echo "You are running in 32-Bit Mode"
Else
    WScript.Echo "You are running in 64-Bit Mode"
End if
```

Note, works only on Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP or higher.